# Filter MS Excel table using formulas

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have created an Excel Table (using Excel > Insert > Table option)

```
[[TABLE1]]
|Name|Location|Salary|
|A   |CA      |100   |
|B   |WA      |200   |
|A   |CO      |800   |
|C   |FL      |350   |
|C   |MO      |400   |
|A   |CA      |100   |
```

I am trying to write a formula, that can calculate the SUM of SALARY column where Name is "A" and location is "CA".
I want to use static table references like (this formula isn't working)

```
SUMIF(TABLE1[TABLE1],[@Name]="A" AND [@Location]="CA",TABLE1[@SALARY])
```

Is there a way to accomplish this.
I am trying to use formula based filter.

Comment: I know how to do this in VBa, but you specifically ask for a worksheet function

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible solutions for you using formulas:

[image]

or

[image]

This second example is an array formula; to enter it, you type everything except the braces `{}`, and when finished press `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`.

In order to modify it to point to a specific table do it similarly like shown below:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,"A",Sheet1!B:B,"CA")
```

Hope that helps you along your way :)